# Create Google Map with Geotagged Flickr Photos

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, flickr

I'm trying to follow [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/linking-up-the-google-maps-and-flickr-apis--webdesign-14199) tutorial to make an embeddable a Google Map that displays all my geotagged Flickr photos as markers showing where they were taken. I'm not sure if something changed with either the GMaps or Flickr APIs since the tutorial was written two years ago, but the markers aren't showing up in the [example given in the tutorial](http://tutsplus.github.io/Google-Maps-and-Flickr-API/part2/tutorial3_part2_google_maps_flickr_mashup.html) nor when I try it with my Flickr photos. I am not very well versed in coding so I can't figure out why they won't show up, and I've scoured the web for hours without any luck. There doesn't seem to be any alternative ways to get this kind of map, so if anyone could offer any help I'd be super grateful!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<title>Google and Flickr API mashup</title> 

<style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<!--Linking to the jQuery library.-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<!--Linking to the Google Maps API-->
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASqSk7-yzQzHkrLVKhjQNBup2Wd-XQkQ0&sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var lat = 0;
var long = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

//Connects to the Flickr API and reads the results of the query into a JSON array. This query uses the 'flickr.photos.search' method to access all the photos in a particular person's user 

account. It also uses arguments to read in the latitude and longitude of each picture. It passes the resultant JSON array to the 'displayImages3' function below.
$.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?

method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=14fca78b18f8e8f4d22216494ea29abf&user_id=136688117%40N05&has_geo=1&extras=geo&format=json&nojsoncallback=?", displayImages3);

function displayImages3(data){

                    //Loop through the results in the JSON array. The 'data.photos.photo' bit is what you are trying to 'get at'. i.e. this loop looks at each photo in turn.
                    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){

                    //Read in the lat and long of each photo and stores it in a variable.
                    lat = item.latitude;
                    long = item.longitude;

                    //Get the url for the image.
                    var photoURL = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_m.jpg';      
                    htmlString = '<img src="' + photoURL + '">';                    
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">' + htmlString + '</div>';

                    //Create a new info window using the Google Maps API
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                         //Adds the content, which includes the html to display the image from Flickr, to the info window.
                         content: contentString
                    });

                    //Create a new marker position using the Google Maps API.
                    var myLatlngMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

                    //Create a new marker using the Google Maps API, and assigns the marker to the map created below.
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlngMarker,
                    map: myMap,
                    title:"Photo"
                    });

                    //Uses the Google Maps API to add an event listener that triggers the info window to open if a marker is clicked.
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(myMap,marker);
                    });                 
        });                 
}

}); 

</script> 

</head>
<body>

<p>Google maps and Flickr API mashup</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="map_canvas"> 
<script>
//Using the Google Maps API to create the map.
var myLatlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.79179, -119.36646);
var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlngCenter,
          zoom: 5,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
</script>
</div>

</body>        
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://gis.yohman.com/up206b/tutorials/api-access-flickr/

Comment: [That example](http://tutsplus.github.io/Google-Maps-and-Flickr-API/part2/tutorial3_part2_google_maps_flickr_mashup.html) has a javascript error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: @eugensunic I have read through that tutorial as well, very helpful and informative. However their example has the exact same problem; the photos/markers don't show up on the map. All I see is a blank map centered on Santa Monica. Does it work for you?

Comment: @geocodezip I appreciate the reply, but because I know next to nothing about coding, that doesn't really help me. Any clues what is causing that error?

Comment: See my answer, there are a few updates.

Answer (score 0):

I just *FINALLY* got this to work! Such a simple solution. I had noticed that Flickr updated its API policy to only allow https and not http. I had changed the API call URL to https manually, but I missed the photoURL. Adding a simple letter 's' after the 'http' in the photoURL resulted in a working embeddable photo map showing my geotagged Flickr photos. Hope this can help someone else out there.

Comment: See my answer, currently some more changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

After two years since the orignal answer and some updates of Flickr policies and jquery, below a full working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<title>Google and Flickr API mashup</title> 

<style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<!--Linking to the jQuery library.-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<!--Linking to the Google Maps API-->
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASqSk7-yzQzHkrLVKhjQNBup2Wd-XQkQ0">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591826/create-google-map-with-geotagged-flickr-photos

var lat = 0;
var long = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){


//Connects to the Flickr API and reads the results of the query into a JSON array. This query uses the 'flickr.photos.search' method to access all the photos in a particular person's user account. It also uses arguments to read in the latitude and longitude of each picture. It passes the resultant JSON array to the 'displayImages3' function below.
$.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=14fca78b18f8e8f4d22216494ea29abf&user_id=136688117%40N05&has_geo=1&extras=geo&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", displayImages3);

function displayImages3(data){

                    //Loop through the results in the JSON array. The 'data.photos.photo' bit is what you are trying to 'get at'. i.e. this loop looks at each photo in turn.
                    $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){

                        //Read in the lat and long of each photo and stores it in a variable.
                        lat = item.latitude;
                        long = item.longitude;

                        //Get the url for the image.
                        var photoURL = 'https://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '_m.jpg';      
                        htmlString = '<img src="' + photoURL + '">';                    
                        var contentString = '<div id="content">' + htmlString + '</div>';

                        //Create a new info window using the Google Maps API
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                             //Adds the content, which includes the html to display the image from Flickr, to the info window.
                             content: contentString
                        });

                        //Create a new marker position using the Google Maps API.
                        var myLatlngMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
                        var myTitle = "" +item.title;

                        //Create a new marker using the Google Maps API, and assigns the marker to the map created below.
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlngMarker,
                        map: myMap,
                        title: item.title
                        });

                        //Uses the Google Maps API to add an event listener that triggers the info window to open if a marker is clicked.
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(myMap,marker);
                        });     

        });                 
}

}); 

</script> 

</head>
<body>

<p>Google maps and Flickr API mashup</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="map_canvas"> 
<script>
//Using the Google Maps API to create the map.
var myLatlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.79179, -119.36646);
var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlngCenter,
          zoom: 5,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
</script>
</div>

</body>        
</html>
```

I had to change:

- The version of *jquery*, since the other version added the HTTP header **X-Requested-With**, which caused the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/method=flickr.photos.search&xxx. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

- The URL parameter *nojsoncallback* has now value *1*, since the old value (*?*) caused the error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&xxxx' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I hope this can help other people.